# AGREGAR TR A TABLA LUEGO DE UN ONCHANGE EN SELECT

Tags: javascript, html5

deseo que me ayuden, deseo agregar un tr a la tabla presionando un select con option , en la funcion de onchange, ya tengo los datos, solo falta agregar a la tabla, mi tabla tiene un tbody, dentro de ese quiero agregarlo, ademas que cada vez que agregue uno no se borre el anterior.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

si estás usando Jquery la solución es simple

```
$("table tbody").append(tu_tr);
```

también puedes usar el 'id' de el tbodyde tu tabla para agregarlo

`$("id_de_tu_tbody").append(tu_tr);`

lo más importante es usar la función .append()

En caso de no usar Jquery puedes fijarte en esta ayuda https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp
 que se basa en jascript puro y con la función insertRow

Comment: Te recomiendo no responder preguntas que no tienen ni el mas mínimo ejemplo por parte del que pregunta, esto por que al no explicarse bien, tu le des un ejemplo que no tiene nada que ver con lo que necesita, y se te califique mal tu respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ricardo, es bueno saberlo, estoy iniciándome en mis aportes en StackOverflow